# Use Multiple API Keys To Get Around Rate Limiting In APIs for NodeJS

Tags: node.js, mongodb, api, alpha-vantage

My client has two API keys for Alpha Vantage with a limit of 5 requests per minute.

If the limit on one is reached, then I want to use the other.

I am using MongoDB as a database.

I was thinking that we can store a variable in MongoDB, but I'm worried about the performance effects in that case.

What is the best (and simplest) way to do this?

The limit is 5 requests/minute. Requesting it to check if the limit is exceed might increase the total time the request takes to execute.

Comment: Ok, and your programming actually question is?

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear. What is the best way to do this?

Comment: You want to use multiple API Keys? Ok. Whats the problem with it? Start coding. If key A returns "bad key", try key B. If that returns "bad key", you reached the rate limits of both API Keys. I dont see a programming question here. Whats your problem with doing it so? Your **programming** question.

Comment: The limit is 5 requests/minute. Requesting it to check if the limit is exceed might increase the total time the request takes to execute.

This is why I asked if storing a variable in MongoDB to keep track of this is a good idea or not.

Comment: Dont check if the limit is reached. Just do your request when needed, and check the return status. When you made a request as needed, and you reached the limit, just use the other key

Comment: I see, thanks! If you post that as an answer, I'll be happy to mark it right :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make your requests as needed, and check the return code from the service.

If the service says/indicate "rate limit reached", try the second API key.
If the limit of the second one is reached, try the first one again.

And so on.

PS: 
There is no need "to check the key" if the limit is reached.
Just make your API call as needed and check the return status.

Just try your keys in a round-robin routine when one reach its limit